# Visual Studio Doesn't Create Xamarin Bin Folder

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to build an iPad project from Visual Studio 2017 for windows, However whenever I try to debug the app I get this error

> Launch failed. The app 'B2C.iPad' could not be launched on 'iPad Air
>   iOS 11.0'. Error: error MT0069: The app directory
>   '/Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/B2C.iPad/acb039527d504c900b2e6c86d8d84d09/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/MobiBusiness.app'
>   does not exist. . Please check the logs for more details.

I noticed that visual studio doesn't create bin folder on the Mac machine although it indicates the build is succeeded.

I tried building the solution without debugging and looked at the log file nothing looked suspicious and there was no error.

does anyone know what might cause this error?

Comment: Is there some setting wrong in Properties-> Build->Output for the corresponding configuration?

Comment: @Kevin no I checked the output path it's what is supposed to be and even if it wasn't there was no build files either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is embarrassing apparently the iPad project wasn't not selected in the build configuration, so needed to select the projects from build --> Configuration Manager